# Sorting displayed results vs. entire results

Tags: user-experience

If I present a user with a table of results from a database which only displays the first 1000 rows, what does the user expect when they re-sort the table?  Do they expect only the displayed results to be sorted (on the client) or do they expect an entirely new result set from the db, sorted accordingly?

For example, if the first (default) table view displays rows A through D, should reversing the sort on that column simply display D through A, or Z through W?

Or should I provide the user with the option to do either?  If so, how could I succinctly phrase the options?

Comment: What makes you believe the people on this site know your user's requirements better than your users? If you are creating invidividual software, ask a user. If you are creating a standard software, ask the person who is responsible for defining the product's requirements (for example, the "product owner").

Comment: @DocBrown Obviously, I'm asking about users in general.

Comment: for whom do you create your software? For "users in general"?

Comment: Pretty much, yep.

Comment: This question belongs on ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no added value to reversing data you can already see (consider the 'head' and 'tail' commands in unix). Even if you only get a snapshot of data, you still need to have access to all of it.

Comment: thanks.  I was really 50/50 on it until I read your post and it suddenly seemed really obvious!  Cheers.